# Choose overloaded method that accepts base or child class as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, overloading

The title is probably poorly written, cause I didn't really know how to describe my problem.
And my problem is described below.
I have two classes:

```
class BaseModel {
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
class ChildModel : BaseModel {
   public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
```

And the third class where I keep instances of above classes:

```
class OverallModel {
   public IEnumerable<BaseModel> Models {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have two methods:

```
public MappedBaseModel MapModel(BaseModel source){
    var result = new MappedBaseModel();
    // do magic for basemodel
}
public MappedBaseModel MapModel(ChildModel source){
    var result = new MappedChildModel(); // MappedChildModel is a child of MappedBaseModel
    // do magic for childmodel
}
```

Now when I iterate over `Models` like that:

```
var list = new List<MappedBaseModel>();
foreach(var model in overallModel.Models){
    list.Add(MapModel(model));
}
```

I get confused, cause the code invokes only `MapModel(BaseModel)`, never `MapModel(ChildModel)`. I made a workaround that checks if a model is of type ChildModel:

```
foreach ...
    if(model is ChildModel)
        list.Add(MapModel(model as ChildModel)); // thats just ugly..
    else
        list.Add(MapModel(model));
```

My problem is that it just looks bad. I don't want to check the type of model just to invoke other overloaded method.
Could you please help me to make it more elegant?
I know I probably didn't provide enough information. Please, if you need to know anything more, just ask and I will try to explain it more deeply.
Also, sorry for my english!
Have a nice day.

Comment: Or use the `dynamic` keyword `list.Add(MapModel((dynamic)model));`

Comment: What is `MappedBaseModel`?  Where have you defined that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38790645/961113) by Anton Gogolev is what should be adopted for the above scenario...*

---

Another way is to use the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd264736.aspx) type. You can simply do:

```
list.Add(MapModel((dynamic)model));
```

and it will call the respective overload.

Comment: `dynamic` gets the job done without rewriting most of the code. Wonderful trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of problems are usually solved using [multiple dispatch](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multiple_dispatch), but that might be an overkill in your scenario. Consider adding a single virtual `Map()` method to your `BaseModel` class:

```
class BaseModel {
    public virtual MappedModelBase Map() {
        var result = new MappedBaseModel();
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}

class ChildModel : BaseModel {
    public override MappedModelBase Map() {
        var result = new MappedChildModel();
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then just:

```
var list = new List<MappedBaseModel>();
foreach(var model in overallModel.Models)
    list.Add(model.Map());
```

Now, if you're into "enterprisey" stuff, here's how to do this double-dispatch style:

```
public class Mapper
{
    public MappedBaseModel MapModel(BaseModel source);
    public MappedBaseModel MapModel(ChildModel source);
}

class BaseModel 
{
    public virtual MappedBaseModel MapWith(Mapper mapper)
    {
        return mapper.MapModel(this);
    }
}

class ChildModel : BaseModel 
{
    public override MappedBaseModel MapWith(Mapper mapper)
    {
        return mapper.MapModel(this);
    }
}

var mapper = new Mapper();
foreach(var model in overallModel.Models)
    list.Add(model.MapWith(mapper));
```

Comment: Nice and extensive answer! The downside is that the conversion from `..Model` to `MappedBaseModel` is now inside the former classes. In a context where e.g. `BaseModel` is a domain model class in a separate assembly, and `MappedBaseModel` is e.g. a view model class, it is undesirable to have `BaseModel` know about the `MappedBaseModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Method `MapModel` (or some another one) should be overriden, not overloaded in that case.